# Bootstrap cards with columns same height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap card and its content is divided into 2 columns (so it can be adjusted on mobile).
One thing that i cant figure out is how to make titles/h6 the same height without involving jquery to set its height... Is it possible to sort this out with flexbox?

This is card structure:

```
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Subtitle</div>
                    <div class="row no-gutters">
                        <div class="col-8 col-12">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h6>Some Post Title</h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 col-12">
                            <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/400/animals" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">posted</div>
                </div>
```

You can see more here and any help would mean a lot.
https://jsfiddle.net/g69phmz7/

Answer (score 0):

Type in 'h-100' in your first div next to card, make sure that this class is in every card.

Answer (score -1):

We can achieve this by using `each` function in jQuery.

```js
let titleHeight = 0; // declaring height as 0
$('.card-title').each(function () { // using each function for card-title class
    if ($(this).height() > titleHeight) { // comparing the heights of each card-title class
        titleHeight = $(this).height(); // we are assigning greater height to card-title
    }
});
$('.card-title').height(titleHeight); //  here we are assigning greater height to all card-title class
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">Subtitle</div>
                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col-8 col-12">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h6 class="card-title">Some Post Title</h6>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-4 col-12">
                                    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/400/animals" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer">posted</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">Subtitle</div>
                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col-8 col-12">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h6 class="card-title">Some Post Title Goes Here And Its Longer</h6>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-4 col-12">
                                    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/400/animals" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer">posted</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header">Subtitle</div>
                            <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col-8 col-12">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <h6 class="card-title">Some Post Title</h6>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-4 col-12">
                                    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/400/animals" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer">posted</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```